# 〜ている + そうだ（様態） =?

Tags: grammar, usage, て-form

How do you add そうだ meaning "looks like" to the 〜ている form? 〜て（い）そうだ?

E.g. 皆が集まっている・食材が揃っている + そうだ = ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 様態{ようたい} ("conjecture"), the correct forms are:

・「皆{みな}が集{あつ}まって**いそう**だ」　"Looks like everyone has come."

・「食材{しょくざい}が揃{そろ}って**いそう**だ」  "Looks like they/we have all the ingredients ready."

・「おもしろそうだ」 No 「い」 before 「そう」.  "It looks interesting."

For 風聞{ふうぶん} ("hearsay"), the correct forms are:

・「皆が集まって**いる**そうだ」 "They say/I hear that everyone has come."

・「食材が揃っている**そう**だ」  "They say/I hear that all the ingredients are ready."

・「おもしろ**い**そうだ」 Needs 「い」.  "They say/I hear that it is interesting."